# Why are the moderator elections only self nominations?

Tags: discussion, election

If I am understanding the AU page about the Mod. elections, the only nominees that we will have the opportunity to vote on will be ones that have nominated themselves.

Could someone please explain the logic in that?

I ask because I have 2 users in mind that I see are very active and I think would make good mods.

I realize that there is a time commitment that some users may not be able to fulfil so that they know that they would not make good mods(or various other sundry reasons that they know that I may not that makes them unsuitable).  However, they would be free to turn down a nomination if it was offered.

The other side of the issue is that a user may make an excellent mod but may not feel comfortable putting themselves forward.  Others could include, not thinking others would want them as Mods., they could have not considered it....ect.  Another user nominating them would at least bring the thought up for them to consider.

Off the top of my head I could think of a few reasons why the election is self nomination only

Spam nominations, nepotism nominations(nominating a friend just because you know them, not because they would be good mod.), quid pro quo nominations(I'll nominate you if you nominate me/give me some special treatment after you are elected)

So getting back to my question(actually a two part question)

1. Am I correct in my reading that the election is self nomination only.
2. if so, why?  it seems to me that AU could me losing out on some good moderators with this policy.

Comment: Quite simply, tell them this. I just nudged someone and told him to stand myself!

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I was considering doing just that, and likely will.  I was just wondering why it is not possible to nominate another user, that is the way it works in most "clubs"(a group of people sharing a common interest as opposed to a political election)

Comment: Just give them a (polite) nudge [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room). Most potential candidates visit chat at least once in their lifetime (some more regularly).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just as people might be uncomfortable putting themselves forward, it might make them uncomfortable to be put up for election. They might be uncomfortable turning it down. They might remain in the running because it's the easier thing to do.

Being a moderator is not just a title you earn for being popular, it's an ongoing job that is often thankless and occasionally quite tough. You should only be part of the election if that's something you want.

But yes, by all means ask people to nominate themselves. If they want to run, they can.

Comment: yea, I can see that some might end up a mod just because it was the easiest thing to do at the time....I was just wondering if there was some overarching policy on AU or SE in general that was the reason....It just seemed odd to me is all....

Answer (score 2):

> Am I correct in my reading that the election is self nomination only?

Yes, at this time the only way to get nominated for being a mod is to nominate yourself.

> If so, why? it seems to me that AU could be losing out on some good moderators with this policy.

After the nominations, there are the Primaries. It's a round of voting where the community does get a say in who becomes a mod by filtering the Nominees.

In addition to the reasons you mentioned, some people just don't want to be mods, and they have their reasons. Forcing them to be mods against their will would be unfair. Also, mods who actually want to do their job do it much better.

And as Journeyman Geek said, you can always have a chat with them about it. Very often, people will know in their heads that they are fit for a certain responsibility but want to be asked to do it; it's a way of knowing they will actually be wanted in that position and also a sign that they are indeed fit for the job.

Comment: "Forcing them to be mods against their will would be unfair" yes I agree, I was not asking for conscription, as I said in my question "they would be free to turn the nomination down"  So if they did not want it they need not accept the nomination.  Some potentially good mods may be too self effacing to put themselves forward but would be willing to accept a nomination by another.  If the community at large disagrees with the opinion of the user who nominated the potential mod that would all come out in the Primaries.....